# Ruby Array find_first object?

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, find

Am I missing something in the Array documentation?  I have an array which contains up to one object satisfying a certain criterion.  I'd like to efficiently find that object.  The best idea I have from the docs is this:

```
candidates = my_array.select { |e| e.satisfies_condition? }
found_it = candidates.first if !candidates.empty?
```

But I am unsatisfied for two reasons:

1. That `select` made me traverse the whole array, even though we could have bailed after the first hit.
2. I needed a line of code (with a condition) to flatten the candidates.

Both operations are wasteful with foreknowledge that there's 0 or 1 satisfying objects.

What I'd like is something like:

```
array.find_first(block)
```

which returns nil or the first object for which the block evaluates to true, ending the traversal at that object.

Must I write this myself?  All those other great methods in Array make me think it's there and I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Either I don't understand your question, or [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is the thing you were looking for.

Comment: No problem, I also often find annoying that ruby documentation doesn't list methods of all inherited or included classes and modules.

Comment: more info: `[1,2,3,5,2].find { |n| puts n; n == 2 } ` iteration stops once it finds the first element it matches.

Answer (score 113):

use array `detect` method if you wanted to return first value where block returns true

```
[1,2,3,11,34].detect(&:even?) #=> 2

OR

[1,2,3,11,34].detect{|i| i.even?} #=> 2
```

If you wanted to return all values where block returns true then use `select`

```
[1,2,3,11,34].select(&:even?)  #=> [2, 34]
```

Comment: `.detect` is exactly what I need. But what's the difference with `.find` then?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger no difference, both are same.`detect` is just an alias to `find` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

Comment: for some consistency I like to follow [The Ruby Style Guide](https://rubystyle.guide/#map-find-select-reduce-size), which favors find

Answer (score 29):

Guess you just missed the find method in the docs:

```
my_array.find {|e| e.satisfies_condition? }
```

Comment: Or if you like code golfing, `my_array.find(&:satisfies_condition?)`

Answer (score 17):

Do you need the object itself or do you just need to know if there *is* an object that satisfies.
If the former then yes: use find:

```
found_object = my_array.find { |e| e.satisfies_condition? }
```

otherwise you can use `any?`

```
found_it = my_array.any?  { |e| e.satisfies_condition? }
```

The latter will bail with "true" when it finds one that satisfies the condition.
The former will do the same, but return the object.