# In Ruby, is there a method similar to `any?` which returns the matching item (rather than `true`)

Tags: ruby, idioms, loops, enumerable

```
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].any? {|n| n % 3 == 0}
=> true
```

What if I want to know *which* item matched, not just *whether* an item matched? I'm only interested in short-circuiting solutions (those that stop iterating as soon as a match is found).

I know that I can do the following, but as I'm new to Ruby I'm keen to learn other options.

```
>> match = nil
=> nil
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each do |n|
..   if n % 3 == 0
..     match = n
..     break
..   end
.. end
=> nil
>> match
=> 3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Array find_first object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381163/ruby-array-find-first-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find {|n| n % 3 == 0} # => 3
```

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false.

So this would also fulfill your 'short-circuiting' requirement. Another, probably less common used alias for `Enumerable#find` is `Enumerable#detect`, it works exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful answer, and a tad quicker than the others. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want the first element for which your block is truthy, use [`detect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].detect {|n| n % 3 == 0}
# => 3
```

If you want the *index* of the first element that matches, use [`find_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find_index {|n| n % 3 == 0}
# => 2
```

If you want *all* elements that match, use [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (this does not short-circuit):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].select {|n| n % 3 == 0}
# => [3, 6]
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks. I accepted emboss's answer as it was posted a minute or two sooner.

Answer (score 3):

If you want short circuiting behavior, you want Enumerable#find, not select

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].find  {|n| n % 3 == 0}
 => 3 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].select  {|n| n % 3 == 0}
 => [3, 6]
```